# Web API core 2.0 cors issue (header is present) not allowed access

Tags: angular, post, cors, http-headers, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to perform post request from angular *http://localhost:4200* to webApi core 2.0 and I'm getting this in my console

> **Failed to load _http://localhost:62066/api/values: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.**

I tried adding cors like this but I get same error; what is the right way to do it?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));
            app.UseCors(builder=> builder.WithHeaders("http://localhost:4200"));
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in startup.cs
add new cors with allowany on everything because when allowing only header request still doesn't work

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowCredentials();
        }));



        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and use it here

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowAll"); //<===
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```